# Editing diffs in-line in vim

Tags: insert-mode

I want to be able to make the changes that I’m making to certain files a lot more visible while I’m editing them.

Does any plugin or functionality of vim allow for viewing the editing history of the document as a patch file? (Similar to the “track changes” visualization feature in Microsoft Word.) I know there are git plugins that can show you which lines are modified/not committed, but I want to be able to view what I’ve deleted inline as well, in case I might need to glance at it again.

Answer (score 1):

There is `mbbill/undotree` plugin that can do it as far as I understood you:

[image]

Comment: See also [Gundo](https://sjl.bitbucket.io/gundo.vim/). I’m not sure if either of these do quite what the OP is looking for, though.